# My account is not matching up with content imported from the Guitars site

Tags: support, migration

This is [an example answer I had posted](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2312/how-do-you-play-a-barre-chord-or-a-chord-with-4-strings/2314#2314) at the Guitars site before it was closed. I have just logged in at https://music.stackexchange.com/ and my answers, questions and reputation are gone.

Is it by design or a bug?
Weren't the accounts from the Guitars site moved along with the questions and answers?

Comment: The accounts weren't migrated, but you should have gained control of your questions and answers when you logged in here.  I think we need a dev to fix this, I can't see anything to help.

Comment: @Matthew Read Can you contact the developers about this problem? I guess as a moderator you have a bigger chance to be heard.

Comment: Yep, I've flagged the question with a note, they'll get to it soon hopefully.

Comment: Noted, I'll take care of this.

Comment: Related: http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/278/reclaiming-questions-from-the-guitar-site?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adjusted the ownership of the post you linked.  That's the only post I see from you though.  You mention "answers, questions" - which seems to imply you had more than 1 post?

Comment: It is possible I posted only this one answer on the main site. Was the meta site migrated too? Because I'm sure I asked a queetion there.

Comment: No, meta was not migrated.

Comment: Was this done for all accounts? Because I too have questions and answer that were migrated, but are no longer linked to my account (same username and openID). Thanks!